# cannot convert from double to Item is the error

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static Item getLeastPricedItem(Item[] s){

    Item min = s[0];
    for(int i = 0;i<s.length;i++){
    if(min.getItemPrice() > s[i].getItemPrice()){
            min = s[i].getItemPrice();
            return Item;
    }
```

Comment: Need more visibility in your question

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your input data and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Well you see that in the second line you have `Item min = s[0];` - this works because `s` is an array of `Item`s. But it cannot work if you try to assign the item's price (which is a double) to the item variable (like here: `min = s[i].getItemPrice()`)

Try something like:

```
public static Item getLeastPricedItem(Item[] s){

    Item min = s[0];
    for(int i = 0;i<s.length;i++){
    if(min.getItemPrice() > s[i].getItemPrice()){
            min = s[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: true...but how do i declare an array with values...it isn't taking any values because of that item type

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question... with `Item[] items = new Item[0];` you can create an array of `Item`s. And then use this as a parameter for your `getLeastPricedItem` function (of course you have to fill the array with some items..)